# Custom column sorting in jquery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatable to display data. I display '--' when there is no data. Currently when the table sorts the data all the '--' comes in the beginning and the order looks like below:

```
--
--
10
20
400
800
```

But I need to make '--' to be displayed last when sorted in ascending order and should look something like below:

```
10
20
400
800
--
--
```

Please let me know how can we get this behavior in jquery datatable?

Comment: What have you tried ? May be examples at http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting may help.

Answer (score 1):

you can use an exstension

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "myorder-pre": function (a) {

    },

    "myorder-asc": function (a, b) {
        if(a == '--' && b != '--')
            return 1;
        else if(b == '--' && a != '--')
            return -1;
        else if(b == '--'&& a == '--')
            return 0;
        else
        {
            a = parseFloat(a);
            b = parseFloat(b);
            return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));

        }
    },

    "myorder-desc": function (a, b) {
        if(a == '--' && b != '--')
            return -1;
        else if(b == '--' && a != '--')
            return 1;
        else if(b == '--'&& a == '--')
            return 0;
        else
        {
            a = parseFloat(a);
            b = parseFloat(b);
            return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));

        }
    }
});
```

myorder-pre is used before all the order call.
myorder-asc when you order asc. Return number negative if a minor b, positive if a major b, 0 if equal.
Desc work adverse

then in the definition of columns of datatable, use

```
"aoColumnDefs": [{ "sType": 'myorder'}]
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. I will update my comments once I incorporate your implementation. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the following code :

```
 $('#example').dataTable( {
    "aaSorting": [[ 4, "desc" ]]
} );
```

For the [reference](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html)

Comment: No, this solution would not work as expected since we need to define the definition on asc and desc sort with regards to '--'. With the code snippet you have given it only sorts in descending order using the default behavior. Hope I am able to express clearly.